# Master Sphere From Dark Ixion

Tags: final-fantasy-10

I was hoping to get 2 Master Spheres from Dark Ixion. I understand from [this site](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Ixion_(Final_Fantasy_X)) that the first form of Dark Ixion does in fact drop Master Spheres one-eighth of the time.

Is it possible that I could get a second on that? I've just defeated Dark Ixion my <strike>eighth</strike>seventeenth time and still no Master Sphere :( I'm pressing on, but I'd like to know that I'm not doing this in vain.

**EDIT:**

There is about a 10% chance (.875<sup>17</sup>) of this happening, if in fact Dark Ixion's first form does drop Master Spheres at a rate of 12.5%. This means I am more likely to get a Master Sphere on the first try than to not get one for 17 tries. Again, I'd just really like to have someone confirm that Dark Ixion's first form does in fact drop Master Spheres.

Answer (score 3):

A one out-of-eighth chance does not mean that you get 1 thing every 8 runs. It means that you have a 12.5% chance of getting that item, every time you kill it. As the linked sites says, it is a rare drop with this chance. So keep on trying!

Comment: Is there anything that affects rare drop rates that I can do? I understand an overkill gets me double but what about getting the rare items?

Comment: Afaik there is no way to increase the drop chances. Googling didn't bring up anything either, unfortunately :(